# C# : SerialPort class and Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

At the moment, I am using the SerialPort class to communicate with my device. To improve the user's experience, I create a thread that can terminate ongoing communications. However, when I start the following piece of code in a thread, the data I will receive from the (SerialPort)port_.Read instruction is actually the same data that I used in the Write instruction (it looks like I can't differentiate from the Read and Write buffer).The code works if I do not put it in a new thread. So why is this happenning, I can only have one communication at the time so there's no way 2 commands can be written in the buffer at the same time.

commTmr is a timer that will stop the while loop after a certain amount of time.

the Thread.Sleep is to make sure the received data can be read in the buffer (I had troubles reading without it)

```
while ((commTmr.timedout == false) && (port_.BytesToRead < threshold))
{
    if (commTmr.TimeElapsed().TotalSeconds > trigg)
    {
        port_.Write(sentData_, 0, nbBytesSend);
        trigg+=0.3;
    }

}

if (commTmr.timedout == true)
{
    return false;
}

else if (!(port_.BytesToRead < threshold))
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    port_.Read(receivedData_, 0, nbBytesRead);
}
```

Comment: There just no scenario where this code can do anything meaningful.  It is very sensitive to timing.  You will call Write() a large number of times until the transmit buffer fills up to capacity.  Blocking the write for a while giving enough time for the BytesToRead to get large enough.  You then *maybe* read something, it is just as likely you won't read anything because their are too many bytes received already.  You then ignore the Read() return value, bad idea, which you patched by using Sleep().  It is completely unclear how it is supposed to work.

Comment: The reason why I loop the Write() instruction is because the device I am working with will often not read my first Write() instruction. That is why I then resend him the command until it anwsers. Although you are right, I shouldn't use the Thread.Sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) states:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

So my guess would be that if you want to use multiple threads, you're going to have to synchronize them using e.g. locks to make sure they do not access the port at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, I used a static SerialPort and it now works proprely.